# Chcp is not recognised as an internal or external command

Tags: windows, postgresql

> ```
> 'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> Password for user postgres:
> psql (14.3)
> WARNING: Console code page (437) differs from Windows code page (1252)
>          8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
>          page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
> ```

Comment: Please help me in solving this issue

Comment: What are you doing to get that output? What happened when you checked the "Notes for windows users" mentioned in the message?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably find the answer here: [https://www.computerhope.com/chcphlp.htm#:~:text=The%20chcp%20command%20is%20used,be%20loaded%2C%20and%20the%20country](https://www.computerhope.com/chcphlp.htm#:%7E:text=The%20chcp%20command%20is%20used,be%20loaded%2C%20and%20the%20country).

> The chcp command is used to supplement the international keyboard and
> character set information, allowing MS-DOS to be used in other
> countries and with different languages. Before the chcp command can be
> used, the nlsfunc must be loaded, and the country.sys must be loaded
> into the config.sys.

Comment: I haven't seen MS-DOS since the mid 1990s. My Windows 10 system does not even have a `config.sys` file. Plus it's hard to find an answer when we barely have a question. OP haven't even shared what command his running.